# Gamma from U238 decay chain

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, radiation, spectroscopy, radioactivity

Where can I find detailed information on the gamma background from the U238 decay chain?

Edit: Thank you for your replies. I need to find all the branching ratios and extract information of all the excited states of the daughter isotopes.

Comment: How detailed do you want? For each decay, the Evaluated Nuclear Structure database (at bnl.gov) has the info, including branching ratios. Tedious to track through all paths of the chain, but doable.

Comment: This [Korean website](http://atom.kaeri.re.kr:8080/ton/nuc4.html) is easy to use and reasonably comprehensive.

Comment: *::Searches the walls for poster to point at::* ... *::realizes he's not at the kind of place that has those posters anymore::*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238#Radium_series_(or_uranium_series) plus ENSDF should do it, but would be a bit of work for you to comb through.

Comment: Oi, people! There really are standard charts for these things and you really *don't* need to go back to the raw data in the ENDF or even a table of the isotopes. I really have worked in places with these thing on *posters* on the wall. Here's one source for the standard charts: http://metadata.berkeley.edu/nuclear-forensics/Decay%20Chains.html (which I found by typing "thorium decay chain" into google; the other really commonl chart is the "radon decay chain").

Comment: Hmmm ... the linked charts don't have the line energies or branching fraction. There are better ones, but you cat get the necessary data from a table of the nucleides if need be. That is certainly easier than parsing ENDFs (unless you've planning to do this programmatically for some other reason).

Comment: @dmckee - yeah, but the OP hasn’t clarified what ‘detailed information’ means to them. At worst they no know where ENDF can be found. And I feel your pain on moving to a different job that doesn’t have those really useful posters on the wall...

Comment: For gamma radiation, the excited states of the daughter product (at least, for the fast-decaying part of the chain) must be quantified; that's not in the shortform charts.

Comment: [A very comprehensive table](http://www.lnhb.fr/nuclear-data/nuclear-data-table/) which you will have to work your way through.

Comment: I once made this: http://homepage.lnu.se/staff/pkumsi/FyA704/Uranium_series.html The isotopes have clickable links for the gory detail. It seems that something bad has happened at LBL to the Isotope Explorer of the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data Files. So the links to the level schemes are dead.